# Calculate electric energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

An electrically driven train has weight 120t and should be brought from 100km/h to a standstill. Calculate the electric recoverable energy by regenerative braking in kilowatt hours, if there is a efficiency of approx 60%.

What I did:
$W=P t=F vt=ma vt=m \frac{v}{t}vt =mv^{2} 
$

I think this is not correct for sure, because I didnt use efficiency anywhere. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: i guess you have to use 60F/100 i.e 60% of F in your calculations. I am not very sure but i think this is to be used!

Answer (score 2):

Please first note that your equation for the work is wrong. You say $P = F v$ which is indeed correct at each moment using *the velocity at that moment*. It is not correct if used for the whole process with $v$ set to the initial velocity.
Using an approach where you actually calculate the power at each point in the process is further not an ideal approach because you need the deceleration - which you just set to be linear over the whole time regime, which could also be debated.
I think a good way to go about this is to calculate the difference in kinetic energy of the train before and after the braking process. This kinetic energy was absorbed by the brakes. If we know that the brakes converted 60% of it into electrical energy, then we can just multiply that energy difference by $0.6$ to obtain the electrical energy the brakes generated by braking.
I leave the calculation of the kinetic energy difference as an exercise to you ;)

Comment: So formula is Ek=mv^2/2, and to calculate difference I should use for v  $0km/h$ for Ek1  and $50km/h$ for Ek2 ?

Comment: where do the 50km/h come from?

Comment: Sorry. I made mistake, I mean on 100 km/h ?

Comment: there you go :)